# Creating "Languages" sub-section of "Skills" sections in CV

Tags: tables, indentation, tabularx, cv

I am creating my CV and I want my "Language" sub-section looks like the following example (i.e. the kind and proficiency are separated into two "columns" and align to the left).
[image: What I want]

I tried following codes, but it looks slightly different from what I want

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ 
    >{\setlength\hsize{1\hsize}} X 
    >{\setlength\hsize{1\hsize}} X }
   \bf {Languages} & {\bf Software} \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
       French & Native 
    \end{tabular} & {Stata, R} \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
      English  & Fluent 
    \end{tabular} & {Latex} \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
       Spanish  & Intermediate 
    \end{tabular} & {Java, HTML} \\
    & {Microsoft Office} 
 \end{tabularx}
 
\end{center}
```

It turns out to be:
[image: What I get]
I hope that "French/English/Spanish" can align with "Languages" and "Native/Fluent/Intermediate" can also align to the left.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like that? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXX}
   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Languages}} & \textbf{Software} \\
       French & Native  & {Stata, R} \\
      English  & Fluent  & {Latex} \\
       Spanish  & Intermediate  & {Java, HTML} \\
    & & {Microsoft Office} 
 \end{tabularx}


\end{document}`

Comment: yes, thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could nest two tabular environments in your tabluarx environment to get the desired alignment:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ 
    >{\setlength\hsize{1\hsize}} X 
    >{\setlength\hsize{1\hsize}} X }
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Languages}}\\
       French & Native \\
       English & Fluent \\
       Spanish & Intermediate \\
       &\\
    \end{tabular} 
    & 
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \textbf{Software}\\ 
        Stata, R \\
        Latex \\
        Java, HTML \\
        Microsoft Office\\ 
    \end{tabular}       
 \end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much! I have another question: it seems that the table has some indentation. The solution provided by "leandriis" does not has such indentation. I tried \noindent  but it seems it is not the reason.